# Maximum party size?

Tags: city-of-heroes

What are the party/group size limits in City of Heroes?

I can find all kinds of resources online that say which games are multiplayer, but nowhere can I find a listing of "this many people can play together in this game."  If someone has a listing like that for MMO-type games, that would be ***awesome***, and save me from basically asking this same question for Champions Online and whatever other MMO's I come across while trying to find one that plays with a larger group right away...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum team size in City of Heroes is **8 players** for normal teaming. You can also set up [Leagues](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/League), which can have a max of **48 players** (6 full teams).

The [Incarnate Trials](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/Incarnate_Trial), [Rikti Mothership](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/Rikti_Ship_Raid) raids, and [Hamidon Raids](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/Hamidon_Raid) are the only times you're really *required* to have a League of players. Even then, the Incarnate Trials don't require a full 48. The Rikti Mothership and Hamidon Raids are zone events which require pretty much a full zone of people to complete.

Otherwise, the majority of the content, including normal missions, [non-Incarnate Trials](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/Trial), and [Task/Strike Forces](http://wiki.cohtitan.com/wiki/Task_Force) can be completed with 8 players.

Comment: In fact, the majority of the content, barring Task Forces, giant monster events and Trials can be completed *solo*.

Comment: @Shadur True! Though there are those crazy people that do solo MoLRSF runs and succeed!

Comment: True; perhaps I should've said that pretty much everything barring trials, TFs and GM events are designed to be theoretically soloable by *anyone*.